# How to construct a matrix with one dimension nullspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, svd, block-matrices, homogeneous-equation

Suppose we have a fat matrix $\boldsymbol{E} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times t}$ and we conduct SVD as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
    \boldsymbol{E} = \boldsymbol{U}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\boldsymbol{V}^\top.
\end{eqnarray}
We extract the first `q` columns to build a basis matrix $\boldsymbol{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times q}$. Based on this basis matrix, we want to obtain a non-zero solution of a homogeneous linear system $\boldsymbol{Dx} = \boldsymbol{0}$,
\begin{eqnarray}
  \label{eq:solve_linear}
  \underbrace{
   \left[
   -\rm{diag}(\boldsymbol{m})\boldsymbol{B} | \boldsymbol{K}
   \right]}_{\boldsymbol{D} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times (q + 3)}}
   \boldsymbol{x}
  =
  \boldsymbol{0},
 \end{eqnarray}
where $\rm{diag}(\cdot)$ denotes diagonal operator, $\boldsymbol{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 3}$ has full column rank, $p > q + 3$. Also $\boldsymbol{m} \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ is a non-zero vector.

The necessary condition to obtain a non-trivial solution for $\boldsymbol{Dx} = \boldsymbol{0}$ is ${\rm null}(\boldsymbol{D}) = 1$, i.e. $\boldsymbol{D}$ has $1d$ nullspace.

**Question:**

Given $\boldsymbol{U}, \boldsymbol{L}, \boldsymbol{m}$, can we automaticaly determine `q` such that ${\rm null}(\boldsymbol{D}) = 1$?

**Note**

One direct method is gradually increasing `q` from $1$ to $p$ until ${\rm rank}(\boldsymbol{D}) = q+3-1$. However, this strategy is time-consuming, I wonder if there is a smart method to solve this problem?